# Get all files in a directory as zip

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3

I was able to get all the files that I want in one dictionary but when I want to read all files, it just returns the first file of that dictionary with API flask and I won't get all the files to return, as the zip would be nice.

```
def download():
"""
API Endpoint responsible for download student
:return:
"""
# If a valid payload wasn't sent just return a 404
if not request.json:
    return jsonify({"results": "404", "description": "invalid payload sent"}), 404
# Load the payload
payload = request.json
# TODO Flesh this out with proper security or else anyone can do a POST and auth in
# TODO Most likely need to create a common module for this
status_code = 200
my_response = {
    "results": {},
    "description": "",
}

if "studentid" in payload and "assignmentid" in payload:
    student_id = payload["studentid"]
    assignment_id = payload["assignmentid"]
    folder = download_for_single_student(student_id,assignment_id)

    return Response(
        folder['Body'].read(),
        mimetype='application/pdf',
        headers={"Content-Disposition": "attachment:report.pdf"}
    )


else:
    status_code = 400
    my_response[
        "description"
    ] = "Please ensure both studentid and assignmentid are in the request payload"
    print("Studentid and/or Assignmentid not found in request")

return jsonify(my_response), status_code
```

Comment: What is the code you provided? What's wrong with it?

Comment: python boto3 i want to return all the files from dictionary but it just return the first file

Answer (score 0):

You can only download one object at a time from Amazon S3 (that is, one object per API call).

There is no functionality to request Amazon S3 to create a Zip file of multiple files / folders.